# After logout, customer name still shows in header beside Sign In link

Tags: header, magento2.2.3, logout

The login user session is expired but in the header, the customer username is showing as logged in.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Any luck on finding a fix for this? I have this happen on fresh installs, old stores, complex and simple themes, various different versions including latest. Usually I see it happen when the user cookie expires, making it all the more frustrating and confusing.

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same?
This could be the cache issue.

Answer (score -1):

found any solutions regarding the issue? I am facing the same problems as you, but even after the session is logged out, the header still shows the username and welcome message.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.